# Is there any shortcut in python to make a tuple list into a given order?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I am current working on make a tuple list to matrix question, and I am give a tuple list like this `[(hello,3),(morning,2),(good,5),(!,1)]`, and what I need to do for a step is to sort it to a list like `[(hello,3),(good,5),(morning,2),(!,1)]`. I know how to do it by creating a new list and doing iteration thing, but I am wondering if there are easier thing we can do by python. Like I can sort this by using a list `[hello, good, morning,!]`. Thank you for helping.

The rule is simply sort the list to a given ordered list.

Comment: What's the logic?

Comment: Make those real python lists. In fact, if you make it a working script with a variable assignment and a compare with the result you want, we can easily test it. Also, by sorting, are you just sorting, isn't `list(sort(your_list))` sufficient?

Comment: What are the rules to determine the order? You can use either `my_list.sort()` or `sorted()` if you know how to define the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say the best way is to construct a dictionary.

Input data:

```
lst = ['hello', 'good', 'morning', '!']
lot = [('hello', 3), ('morning', 2), ('good', 5), ('!', 1)]
```

Code:

```
dct = dict(lot)
print([(i, dct[i]) for i in lst])
```

Output:

```
[('hello', 3), ('good', 5), ('morning', 2), ('!', 1)]
```

This makes the words keys and numbers values of the dictionary, and get's the values in order of the `lst`.

This is much more efficient than the other answers, since `sorted` is a pretty massive function.